# Is it possible to use glidejs inside a vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, glidejs

I would like to use `glidejs` inside a `vuejs` component, although I couldn't make it work so far.

Is it possible to achieve this? Does `vuejs` support such a thing?

my code:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="glide">
            <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
                <ul class="glide__slides">
                    <li class="glide__slide">0</li>
                    <li class="glide__slide">1</li>
                    <li class="glide__slide">2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
                <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<">prev</button>
                <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">">next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide'
new Glide('.glide').mount() // this is probably wrong
    export default {
        name: 'Carousel',
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    @import '../assets/styles/glide/glide.core.min.css';
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main fix needed in your code is to move the `Glide` initialization to the [`mounted()` hook](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#mounted), which runs when the component has mounted in the document, enabling the `.glide` selector given to the `Glide` constructor to be found:

```html
<script>
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide'

export default {
  mounted() {
    new Glide('.glide').mount()
  },
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-glidejs?file=src/components/Carousel.vue)